# Why can't the OCR1A register be set to 1 to get a 8MHz PWM?

Tags: pwm

The max PWM frequency that can be achieved with an Arduino is by using the PWM fast mode with the pre-scaler set at 1 and the TOP counter value at 3, getting 4MHz

f_OC = 16000000/(1(1 + 3)) = 4000000

Why can't be the TOP value set at 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because then you only have 1-bit PWM. And there aren't an awful lot of applications for 1-bit PWM.

Comment: Yeah, I understand isn't quite useful, but there is some kind of physical limitation? if I set the TOP =1, what will happen?

Comment: There's no physical limitation, there's just no *point*. The DC of the signal will be either 0% or 100%, which means you've emulated a normal GPIO except that you're consuming the power to run the clock as well.

Comment: You're right I was thinking on three values.

Comment: And what about TOP =2 ?